# How to remove duplicate records but keep one in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using Microsoft Access to keep my database.

I created a course development database in Microsoft Access.

The original dataset includes information on who developed each course, with one person developing multiple courses and each course having multiple developers, forming a many-to-many relationship between the developer and course tables.

To organize the developer table, I used the query wizard to find and remove duplicate data, as there were many cases where the same name and phone number appeared but with different affiliations.

However, I want to keep one record for each unique name and phone number combination and delete the rest. It seems like the query will delete all instances of duplicate data, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

This is how my data looks like:

[image: Origninal]

This is my outcome I want to make

[image]

I tried Query wizard. Here's the SQL for the query I created:

```
SELECT Developer.Name, Developer.Affiliation, Developer.Position, Developer.Cell Phone 

FROM Developer 

WHERE ((Developer.Name) in (SELECT [Name] FROM [DEVELOPER] As Tmp GROUP BY [Name],[Affiliation],[Position],[Cell Phone] HAVING Count(*)>1 And [Affiliation] = [DEVELOPER].[Affiliation] And [Position] = [Developer].[Position] And [Cell Phone] = [Developer].[Cell Phone])))

ORDER BY Developer.Name, Developer.Affiliation, Developer.Position, Developer.Cell Phone.
```

Comment: What's the query you're using?  `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table` will return unique values.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Hello. I used Query Wizard -  Find Duplicates - Selected developer table and selected Name, Affiliation, Position, Cell Phone. I will edit the question and add my SQL

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I added the SQL for the Query Wizard I used. This returns all the records with same Name, Affiliation, Position and Phone Number just like picutre 1.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT [Name], Affiliation, Position, [Cell Phone], Office FROM Developer ORDER BY [Name], Affiliation, Position, [Cell Phone], Office` should work.  I'd consider changing `Name` as that's a reserved word for Access.  You didn't show Office in your SQL - I take it that's an oversight.

Comment: Note - as you're using a single table there's no need to add the table name to each field, although the wizard would have added them and plenty of brackets to (most of which aren't needed).

Comment: There is _no way_ to do this in SQL as you have no unique key. However, you can loop the records in a `DAO.Recordset` in VBA and delete the record if it is identical to the last read record.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you for the answer. This returns the output I wanted. So, I am guessing there is no way to find list of duplicates first and then delete all records except for one distinct combination of Name, Affiliation, Position Phonenumber like I explained in the question Right? Instead, I just have to extract dinstince combination of name, affiliation, postion and number.

Comment: @Gustav Hello. You mentioned unique key, do you refer to the single primary key? I wanted to identify primary key but since the developers have developed multiple courses and their personal information has changed over time, I was unable to come up with a way to address unique primary key. Maybe composite key is ok?

Comment: Yes, a composite unique key is perfect. However - given your sample data - even that you don't have. A simple solution, if you have that option, is to add an _AutoNumber_ field to the table.

Comment: @Gustav As far as I know, composite key is a combination of multiple fields, right? I did not write all the fields in the sample data above. There is email, major, university, graduation year, etc. So if I could make a composite key, is there any other option to solve the problem above? I think adding an AutoNumber field will not solve the problem as there are like 8 fields with same name, and phone number but different job position or affiliation. In some cases, job position and affiliation remain same but phone number has changed.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have one more question. There are 6 more fields in the developer table (university, address, major, grad year, etc). But  the SQL you wrote returns just 5 fields (Name, Affiliation, Position, Cell Phonem Office). If I want to extract records with distinct 5 fields but the format of result includes all fields from the original table, how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The SQL I gave returns five fields.  You want to extract distinct records from those five fields.  Not sure what you mean by "but the format of result includes all fields from the original table".  You can add the extra fields to the query to return them, if the records aren't distinct when including them then you'll get duplicates in the first five fields again.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Sorry my English isn't good. So I want my output to include all the fields but those fields must be the fields with distince name, affiliation, postion and phone number.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Is this possible? `SELECT * FROM Developer WHERE DISTINCT Name, Affiliation, Position, Phonenumber`

Answer (score 0):

The very fast method is to write the distinct values to a new table:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Name], [Affiliation], [Position], [Cell Phone], [Office]
INTO 
    DeveloperUnique
FROM 
    Developer;
```

Comment: Is this possible? `SELECT * FROM Developer WHERE DISTINCT Name, Affiliation, Position, Phonenumber`

Comment: You could try - won't take a minute ...

Answer (score 0):

X table data we have
Step 1: create query wizard for duplicates
step 2: create query wizard for unmatched using first query wizard(duplicate)
step 3: create append query and both separately append in Y table

Y table we don't have any duplicate record, we get all.

Comment: I believe that the OP tried your step 1 and did not get his desired result, so I'm not sure that your answer will help him resolve his problem. Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post sample queries?